# Multiple plot in the same figure

Tags: r, plot

I have several data and I need to plot them compactly in a picture like this:
[image]

I already tried `par()` `layout()` and `ggplot()` but plots are displayed so far each other.
I need them to be very close, as if they were in the same plot with a different y (e.g. `plot1 y=0, plot2 y=1, plot3 y=3` and so on..)

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you let me know if this picture is what you were talking about? It got added in a suggested edit but I can't find any trace of it in your message.

Comment: Yes, I would need a series of plot like that in a picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is `ggplot` version using `facet_grid`:

```
df <- data.frame(a=runif(3e3), b=rep(letters[1:3], 1e3), c=rep(1:1e3, 3))
ggplot(df, aes(y=a, x=c)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + facet_grid(b ~ .)
```

[image]

Comment: @mirkuz, glad this helped.  If either answer satisfies your need please check one of them as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

That can be acquired using the layout, also, but maybe an easier approach is to set the graphical parameters in a suitable way.

Function `par()` let's you specify the number of panels in a single figure using the argument `mfrow`. It takes a vector of two numbers, that specify the number sub-figure rows and columns. For example, `c(2,1)` would create two rows of figure,s but only a single column. That's what is in your example figure. You can change the number of figure rows to the number of sub-figures you would like to plot vertically.

In addition, the margins around each sub-figure can be set using the argument `mar`. The margins are specified in the order of 1. bottom, 2. left, 3. top., and 4. right. Making the bottom and top margins smaller would draw your sub-figures closer together.

In R this could look something like the following:

```
# Simulate some random data
a<-runif(10000)
b<-runif(10000)

# Open a new plot windows
# width: 7 inches, height: 2 inches
x11(width=7, height=1)

# Specify the number of sub-figures
# Specify the margins (top and bottom are 0.1, left and right are 2)
# Needs some experimenting with to get these right
par(mfrow=c(2,1), mar=c(0.1,2,0.1,2))

# Plot the figures
barplot(a)
barplot(b)
```

The resulting figure should roughly resemble this:

[image: Resulting image]